# i want to make a toggle div by react spring but i got this error (TypeError: Object(...) is not a function)

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

i  want to make a toggle div by react spring but i got this error (TypeError: Object(...) is not a function)

```
import React , {useState} from 'react'
import { useSpring ,animated} from 'react-spring/renderprops'
 const Togg =()=>{
       const  [isToggled,setToggle]= useState(false);
          const fade = useSpring({
          opacity : isToggled ? 1 : 0
             });
           return(
             <div>
           <animated.h1 style={fade}>hello</animated.h1>
           <button onClick={()=>setToggle(!isToggled)}>Toggle This</button>
            </div>
            );
            }
    
        export default Togg
```

Comment: Where is the error occurring?

Comment: in this line            const fade =  useSpring({opacity : isToggled ? 1 : 0})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import statement should be `import {useSpring, animated} from 'react-spring'`.